# Include header in grep of specific csv columns

Tags: bash, csv, grep

I am trying to extract relevant information from a large csv file for further processing, so I would like to have the column names (header) saved in my output mini-csv files.

I have:

```
grep "Example" $fixed_file | cut -d ',' -f 4,6 > $outputpath"Example.csv"
```

which works fine in generating a csv file with two columns, but I would like the header information to also be included in the output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command grouping and add `head -1` to the mix:

```
{ head -1 "$fixed_file" && grep "Example" "$fixed_file" | cut -d ',' -f 4,6 ;} \
         >"$outputpath"Example.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to replace your multiple-command pipeline with a single awk script.

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    OFS=FS=","
  }

  NR==1;

  /Example/ {
    print $4,$6
  }
' "$fixed_file" > "$outputpath/Example.csv"
```

If you want your header only to contain the headers fields fields 4 and 6, you could change this to:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    OFS=FS=","
  }

  NR==1 || /Example/ {
    print $4,$6
  }
' "$fixed_file" > "$outputpath/Example.csv"
```

Awk scripts consist of pairs of `condition { statement }`. A missing statement assumes you want to print the line (which is why `NR==1;` prints the header).

And of course, you could compact this into a one-liner:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1||/Example/{print $4 FS $6}' "$fixed_file" > "$outputpath/Example.csv"
```